# Getting XML file not in the same root as the source file in Java

Tags: java, xml

I have a problem where I can't seem to link to a xml file, see the layout below:

Folder Name
 -Folder
 -Folder
 -SourceFiles
    -packagename
           -all my java files
 -myXml.xml

Build is where all the class files etc is stored.
src is where the projectFolder is, and within it the java files

Code I am using to link XML File for Synth:      SynthDialog.class.getResourceAsStream("synthtest/synthDemo.xml")

Now I want to link to the myXML.xml file in the top-level folder. It would be the PHP Equivelent of ../../Folder/

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be attempting to access the file using `getResourceAsStream` with a relative name.  If that is the case, then the resource should be in located in a JAR file or directory on the classpath, and the location will be resolved relative to the FQN of the class.

I can't tell where the ".class" files are located in the tree, or how your classpath is set up, so I can't be more specific.

---

**UPDATED**

If you are executing out of that build directory, then your build process needs to copy the XML file to the appropriate place in the `build` tree so that the class-relative path ends up referring to the file.  (Or use a path that starts with "/" so that you don't depend on the classes FQN at all.)

In the long term, you will probably execute out of a JAR file, and the data file will need to be inside it.

Comment: Please see my post now for more info please

Answer (score 0):

Use "getSystemResourceAsStream" instead of "getResourceAsStream" to access files outside of your codebase.

Comment: Ok, but how would I link to the file then, the complete c:// etc or how?

Comment: Ultimately, you need a qualified path, as your relative path would probably be relative to JAVA_HOME/bin.  I would recommend appending your relative path to a variable that holds the current directory of your context (e.g. using getContextPath() off your Request object).